# Should I be concerned? Vue 2 app, without a discernable template

Tags: vuejs2

Frontend newb. here-- I'm going through our Vue 2 app, hoping to recreate it as a Vue  3 app. Could it be that, in our existing Vue 2 app., the root app ('new Vue') does not possess a template hook, and that instead each of its components will then be mounted, which would serve as a template?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Vue 3, the composition API allows for a more flexible and modular approach to building Vue applications compared to the options API in Vue 2. In Vue 3, you can create components using the defineComponent function and then compose them together in the root instance without the need for a template hook in the root instance itself.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sorry I couldn't share our code. I was referring to our existing Vue 2 app, not having a template hook. I'm more confused now. I'll update the Q.

Answer (score 0):

This was down to a misunderstanding on my part. I hadn't realised the power of Vue. It doesn't *only* replace the html element with the specific id, e.g. "app", it also looks inside that element for any other elements that share an id with any of its components, and swaps those.